# Delay when starting or refreshing website Visual Studio 2013 Express and Windows 10

Tags: visual-studio-2013, windows-10

Since updating to Windows 10, I experience delays (up to a minute) when starting the website I'm developing. The browser opens and it is attempting to fetch the URL but it just sits there spinning until at some point VS kicks back in finally the page loads. This includes new projects since the upgrade to Windows 10 and older projects built before the update to Windows 10. If I make a client side change (ie change some HTML), save the file and then refresh the browser, I also get massive delays. Any ideas?

In addition, during the delay nothing is posted to the output window in VS. The eventual page load coincides with messages appearing in the output window, indicating that the delay is occurring at the VS end.

Comment: I haven't seen that with VS 2015, or 2013.  I would also suggest the Community Edition, which is basically the Pro variant for free.

Comment: ok .. that slipped under my radar .. didn't even know 2013 CE existed .. thanks

Comment: Might as well go for the goods and get 2015 :)

Comment: Yeah I have 2015 .. but as I'm half way through this project I was avoiding switching IDEs